# Oracle selection query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

We have two tables TABLE1 and TABLE2.

TABLE1 has 3 columns i.e. ROLL, LINE, AMT

```
 CREATE TABLE TABLE1( ROLL NUMBER(4), LINE NUMBER(2), AMT NUMBER(4,4) );

 INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(101, 1, 50);
 INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES(102, 2, 60);

  ROLL     LINE      AMT
 -------------------------
  101        1        50
  102        2        60
```

---

TABLE2 has  6 columns i.e. ROLL, LINE, AMT_PRI_CD, AMT_PRI, AMT_SEC_CD, AMT_SEC.

```
 CREATE TABLE TABLE2 VALUES(ROLL NUMBER(4), LINE NUMBER(2), AMT_PRI_CD VARCHAR2(3), AMT_PRI NUMBER(4,4), AMT_SEC_CD VARCHAR2(3), AMT_SEC NUMBER(4,4) ); 

 INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES(101, 1, ‘ABCD’, 50, ‘BCDE’, 40);
 INSERT INTO TABLE2 VALUES(102, 2, ‘BCDA’, 40, ‘BCED’,  60);

  ROLL    LINE    AMT_PRI_CD    AMT_PRI    AMT_SEC_CD    AMT_SEC
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
  101      1         ABCD         50        BCDE          40
  102      2         BCDA         40        BCED          60
```

---

The resultant table should be

```
 ROLL    LINE    AMT_PRI_CD    AMT_PRI    AMT_SEC_CD    AMT_SEC
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
 101      1       ABCD          50        ABCD            50
 102      2       BCED          60        BCED            60
```

From above two tables, we can see that ROLL & LINE columns are common and

if value of AMT column from TABLE1 is equal to  value of AMT_PRI column from TABLE2 select all columns from TABLE2 by populating AMT_SEC and AMT_SEC_CD column values same as AMT_PRI and AMT_PRI_CD column values.

if value of AMT column from TABLE1 is equal to  value of AMT_SEC column from TABLE2 select all columns from TABLE2 by populating AMT_PRI and AMT_PRI_CD column values same as AMT_SEC and AMT_SEC_CD column values.

Is it something we need to use CASE WHEN query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare the values in a `case` expression and return the appropriate column, e.g.:

```
create table table1( 
  roll number(4), line number(2), amt number 
);
create table table2 (
  roll number(4), line number(2), 
  amt_pri_cd varchar2(4), amt_pri number,
  amt_sec_cd varchar2(4), amt_sec number 
); 

insert into table2 values(101, 1, 'ABCD', 50, 'BCDE', 40);
insert into table2 values(102, 2, 'BCDA', 40, 'BCED', 60);

insert into table1 values(101, 1, 50);
insert into table1 values(102, 2, 60);

select roll, line,
       case
         when amt = amt_pri then amt_pri_cd
         when amt = amt_sec then amt_sec_cd
       end amt_pri_cd,
       case
         when amt = amt_pri then amt_pri
         when amt = amt_sec then amt_sec
       end amt_pri,
       case
         when amt = amt_pri then amt_pri_cd
         when amt = amt_sec then amt_sec_cd
       end amt_sec_cd,
       case
         when amt = amt_pri then amt_pri
         when amt = amt_sec then amt_sec
       end amt_sec
from   table1
join   table2
using  ( roll, line );

ROLL    LINE AMT_PRI_CD   AMT_PRI AMT_SEC_CD   AMT_SEC   
 101       1 ABCD              50 ABCD              50 
 102       2 BCED              60 BCED              60
```

Comment: Is there any possibility of using WHERE EXISTS statement query for this problem?

Comment: Why do you want to use `exists`?